# Pygame Ground Collision Detection and Position Reset

Tags: python, position, pygame, reset, collision

Assuming that my character is falling, and headed toward some sprite platform, and I flag that my character has landed once a collision is detected, what is the best way to reset my character's position - so that he is above the platform's rectangle or so that he is still clipping it?

My concerns are that if my character is above the platform's rectangle, than my function fall() will be called because he isn't touching anything, and if my character is clipping the platform's rectangle, than my jump() function may be hindered, because it may think he's landed as soon as he takes off. Obviously there are work arounds for either, but I'm really just looking for the convention, if there is one.

(I can post code if necessary, but the code isn't the issue.  I'm really just looking for the right method)

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

I would have him touching the platform so that `fall()` is not called again.

> and if my character is clipping the platform's rectangle, than my jump() function may be hindered, because it may think he's landed as soon as he takes off.

In the jump() function, when it moves the character make it so it cannot stop until it moves a minimum of x pixels.

You can do this by making a boolean to `False` at the beginning of `jump()` and having a counter to make it `True` after x pixels have been traversed. Make sure that x is just enough to get the character to stop clipping the platform, and not too much so it can collide with other things.

Once it has moved x pixels, then allow the collision testing to commence to see when the character hits something again.

So for example:

```
MINIMUM_DISTANCE = x 
# ^ how many pixels you want to move to stop clipping

count = 0 #used for counting

def jump():
    global count
    in_air = False
    #do your movements here, and increase count each time you move a pixel
    if count >= MINIMUM_DISTANCE: in_air=True
    if in_air:
        #collision detection here
        #once there is a collision:
        if collision:
            count = 0
    return
```

And just for future reference, its better to post the code you have, even if it isn't a code related error. just so we can maybe see and get a feel for your approach

hope I could help

Comment: Makes sense to me.  Thanks!

(I realize this is a very delayed response, haha)

Comment: @MikeRobideau haha no worries about the lateness.  If it helped, remember to accept the answer so that people dont think it still needs answering!